# Reallocating vector move symantics

Tags: c++, move

Hi I am trying to understand how moving works when a vector reallocates itself. Can someone please help me understand the following function

```
void StrVec::reallocate(){

     auto newcapacity = size() ? 2 * size() : 1;
     auto newdata = alloc.allocate(newcapacity);
     auto dest = newdata;
     auto elem = elements; // points to the next element in the old array
     
     for (size_t i = 0; i != size(); ++i)         
          alloc.construct(dest++, std::move(*elem++));
     
     free();  // free the old space once we've moved the elements

     elements = newdata;     
     first_free = dest;     
     cap = elements + newcapacity;
}
```

What is happening in the for loop? Since `free()` will remove the previous vector, so the only way to have a contiguous memory is to copy the previous vector, how is move helping here?

Comment: "Moving" does perform a copy. The difference is that the original is left in "valid but unspecified" state.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat so you mean to say move is here for the previous vector rather than the new vector ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You said you expected to see a copy, and a copy would work here. But moving is generally faster, and the only difference is what happens to the original objects, which doesn't matter because they're getting destroyed immediately.

Comment: Because the old array is about to be destroyed, very shortly no one is going to care what was in the old array. If you can rip the guts out of the old array elements and transplant them to the corresponding element in the new array, as opposed to copying them, is work prevented and time saved.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if what ends up happening is copy, how is move faster?

Comment: @Nischal You need a C++ book/tutorial. We can't summarize the move semantics to you in a few comments. *"if what ends up happening is copy"* I didn't say that. I said copying would work too.

Comment: @Nischal Imagine a vector of `string` objects. A `string` contains a pointer to character data elsewhere in memory (let's ignore Short-String-Optimization for now). The new array needs its own `string` objects, but in a move scenario, the contents of the old `string`s can be moved into the new `string`s without re-allocating any character data, just moving the pointers around. In a copy scenario, each new `string` would have to make a complete copy of an old `string`'s character data for itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, this is simple and straightforward. I also did some research and arrived at the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

> What is happening in the for loop?

Each of the elements in the old storage are moved into the new storage.

> how is move helping here?

Moving is often more efficient than copying.

Comment: by move, do you mean copy here? since in the next step the previous vector is destroyed so the contents will be destroyed as well. So how is move helping here? Isn't it same as copy?

Comment: @Nischal By move I mean move. Moving can be same as copying. Whether it is same depends on the type of the element. Move is helping by being faster (in case of types whose move isn't same as copy).